# Not entering into success event of Ajax in .net MVC Framework

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

My Ajax Code is

```
    function UserCheck() {

            var q = document.getElementById("username").value;
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Checks","Ajaxx")',
    data: {
        'userdata': q
    },
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "html",
     success: function (data) {
         //------------
         alert("insuccess");
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = data.toString();
    }
});
        }
```

Am using this ajax code to check whether the entered username is exists 
My controller name is Ajaxx and method is checks

Method is

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CinemaApplication.Models; 
namespace CinemaApplication.Controllers
{
    public class AjaxxController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Ajaxx/
        [HttpPost]
        public string Checks(string userdata)
        {
            string tmp = "success";
            using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
            {
                var SeachData = db.Logins.Where(x => x.username == userdata).FirstOrDefault();
                if (SeachData != null)
                {
                    tmp = "Fail";
                }
            }
            return tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the whole code of my controller. It is dedicated to this ajax .
the value of username field is correctly arrived in q ,but i don't know that the method (Checks) in controller(Ajaaxx) is working

Comment: Could you post your entire controller code?  Does it make it into the Checks method at all?

Comment: i have only one method (Checks) in my controller.

Comment: And does it make it into the Checks method?  If not, what is triggering your javascript function then?

Comment: javascript is triggering from a view in another controller

Comment: Put breakpoints your action method and see what is happening. Is your ajax call returning 200 OK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax code

```
function Checks()
            {

            var unm = document.getElementById("username").value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Ajaxx/Checks",
                data: '{user:"' + unm + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(result)
                {
                    var mess = $("#Status");
                    if (result)
                    {
                        mess.html('Username available');
                        mess.css("color", "green");
                    }
                    else{
                        mess.html('Username not available');
                        mess.css("color", "red");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

var mess is holding the id of the span
Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Checks(string user)
        {
            bool tmp = true;
            using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
            {
                var SeachData = db.Logins.Where(x => x.username == user).FirstOrDefault();
                if (SeachData != null)
                {
                    tmp = false;
                }
            }
            return Json(tmp);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following properties in your jquery call:

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```